# RichEditBox and MVVM

Tags: uwp

1. I am trying to think of a way to affect my `"EditBox"` with my three buttons,
2. I want to change the font name and size, when I change the `comboboxes` variables.

I have a switch statement and tags, to define each button
I tried to change the size of the font, by calling the `CharacterFormat`
I already have a VM set up for this, but I dont now how to pass th tag of each button

```
<Page x:Name="Main"
  x:Class="uwpEvernote.View.NotesPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:uwpEvernote.View"
  xmlns:vm="using:uwpEvernote.ViewModel"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.Resources>
    <vm:NotesVM x:Key="VM" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="enabled"
                     Color="#0078D4" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="disabled"
                     Color="Transparent" />
</Page.Resources>

<RelativePanel x:Name="Container"
               DataContext="{StaticResource VM}"
               Background="{ThemeResource SystemChromeLowColor}"
               Loaded="Container_Loaded">
    <MenuBar x:Name="menuBar">
        <MenuBarItem Title="File">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New notebook"
                            Command="{Binding NewNotebookCommand}">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE82D;" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New Note"
                            Command="{Binding NewNoteCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedNotebook}">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE70B;" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit"
                            Command="{Binding ExitCommand}">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE106;" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
        </MenuBarItem>

    </MenuBar>
    <ListView x:Name="Notebook"
              RelativePanel.Below="menuBar"
              Width="140"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNotebook, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding NoteBooks}"
              RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="Notes"
              Width="140"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"
              RelativePanel.Below="menuBar"
              RelativePanel.RightOf="Notebook"
              RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <CommandBar x:Name="commandBar"
                RelativePanel.Below="menuBar"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="Notes"
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,10,20,10"
                Background="{ThemeResource  SystemChromeLowColor}">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <AppBarButton x:Name="textToSpeech"
                              Icon="Microphone"
                              Click="Actions_Click"
                              Tag="0"
                              ToolTipService.ToolTip="Text to speech" />
                <AppBarButton x:Name="FormatBoltText"
                              ToolTipService.ToolTip="Bold"
                              Icon="Bold"
                              Tag="1"
                              Click="Actions_Click" />
                <AppBarButton x:Name="formatItalicText"
                              ToolTipService.ToolTip="Italic"
                              Icon="Italic"
                              Tag="2"
                              Click="Actions_Click" />
                <AppBarButton x:Name="formatUnderlineText"
                              ToolTipService.ToolTip="Underline"
                              Icon="Underline"
                              Tag="3"
                              Click="Actions_Click" />
                <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                          Tag="1"
                          x:Name="fontBox"
                          SelectionChanged="ComboChanged"
                          Width="150" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="fontSizeBox"
                          Tag="2"
                          SelectionChanged="ComboChanged"
                          IsEditable="True"
                          Margin="10,0,0,0"
                           />
            </StackPanel>

        </CommandBar.Content>

    </CommandBar>
    <RichEditBox x:Name="richEbitBox"
                 TextChanged="Cotent_TextChanged"
                 RelativePanel.RightOf="Notes"
                 RelativePanel.Below="commandBar"
                 RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                 RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="Notebook"
                 Margin="0,0,10,40" />
    <CommandBar Background="{ThemeResource  SystemChromeLowColor}"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="Notes"
                RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="richEbitBox"
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                Margin="0,0,10,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Count"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="|"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="charactersCount"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
</RelativePanel>
```

```
  public ObservableCollection<NoteBook> NoteBooks { get; set; }

    private NoteBook _SelectedNotebook;

    public NoteBook SelectedNotebook {
        get { return _SelectedNotebook; }
        set {
            if (value != _SelectedNotebook) {
                _SelectedNotebook = value;
                //OnPropertyChanged("SelectedNotebook");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public NewNoteCommand NewNoteCommand { get; set; }
    public NewNotebookCommand NewNotebookCommand { get; set; }
    public ExitCommand ExitCommand { get; set; }


    public NotesVM() {

        NewNoteCommand = new NewNoteCommand(this);
        NewNotebookCommand = new NewNotebookCommand(this);
        ExitCommand = new ExitCommand(this);
        NoteBooks = new ObservableCollection<NoteBook>();
        Notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>();

        ReadNotebooks();
    }

    public void CreateNotebook() {

        var newNotebook = new NoteBook() {
            Name = "New notebook"
        };

        DatabaseHelper.Insert(newNotebook);
    }

    public void CreateNote(int id) {

        var newNote = new Note() {
            NotebookId = id,
            CratedTime = DateTime.Now,
            UpdatedTime = DateTime.Now,
            Title = "New note"
        };

        DatabaseHelper.Insert(newNote);
    }

    public void ReadNotebooks() {

        using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(DatabaseHelper.dbFile)) {

            var notebooks = conn.Table<NoteBook>().ToList();

            NoteBooks.Clear();
            foreach (var item in notebooks) {
                NoteBooks.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ReadNoote() {

        using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(DatabaseHelper.dbFile)) {

            if (SelectedNotebook != null) {
                var notes = conn.Table<Note>().Where(n => n.NotebookId == SelectedNotebook.Id).ToList();

                Notes.Clear();
                foreach (var item in notes) {
                    Notes.Add(item);
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

}

```
        public NotesPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var fonts = CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies();
        fontBox.ItemsSource = fonts;
        var arrList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 73; ++i) {
            arrList.Add(i);
        }
        fontSizeBox.ItemsSource = arrList;
    }

    private void Cotent_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        richEbitBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out string value);
        charactersCount.Text = (value.Length - 1).ToString();
    }

    private async void Actions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        var id = sender as Button;

        switch (id.Tag) {

            case "0":
                using (SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer()) {
                    await recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
                    var result = await recognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
                    var dialog = new MessageDialog(result.Text, "Text spoken");
                    await dialog.ShowAsync();

                    richEbitBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out string value);
                    richEbitBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, value += result.Text);
                }
                break;
            case "1":
                if (richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Bold == FormatEffect.On) {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.Off;
                    FormatBoltText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["disabled"];
                } else {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.On;
                    FormatBoltText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["enabled"];
                }
                break;
            case "2":
                if (richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Italic == FormatEffect.On) {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Italic = FormatEffect.Off;
                    formatItalicText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["disabled"];
                } else {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Italic = FormatEffect.On;
                    formatItalicText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["enabled"];
                }
                break;
            case "3":
                if (richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Underline == UnderlineType.Single) {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Underline = UnderlineType.None;
                    formatUnderlineText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["disabled"];
                } else {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Underline = UnderlineType.Single;
                    formatUnderlineText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["enabled"];
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ComboChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {

        var id = sender as ComboBox;

        switch (id.Tag) {

            case "1":
                //Todo implement new font
                string fontName = id.SelectedItem.ToString();
                richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Name = fontName;
                break;
            case "2":
                var size = (float)id.SelectedItem;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Container_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        fontBox.Text = richEbitBox.Document.GetDefaultCharacterFormat().Name;
        fontSizeBox.Text = richEbitBox.Document.GetDefaultCharacterFormat().Size.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

1. change the size of the font, when I drop down and select a number, and the font name
2. Eliminate everything from the code behind (I dont know if is a bad practice to use it or not)

Comment: By the way every time I run the recognizer, it creates a new line, and I dont want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I don't know how to pass the tag of each button.

In which scenario you want to pass the tag of each button? What is the specific behavior?

> > Every time I run the recognizer, it creates a new line, and I don't want that.

This is because when you use this code `richEbitBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out string value);` to get the text, it will automatically add **'\r'** at the end of the text. By testing, you can use `TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf` to set TextGetOptions, it won't create a new line.

```
richEbitBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf, out string value);
richEbitBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, newText += result.Text);
```

Or after getting the text, first remove the last character and then set the new value.

```
richEbitBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out string value);
string newText = value.Remove(value.Length - 1);
richEbitBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, newText += result.Text);
```

**Update:**

> > How can I change the size of my font.

You can try the following code to change the size of richEditBox.

```
private void ComboChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var id = sender as ComboBox;
    switch (id.Tag)
    {
        case "2":
        richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Size = Convert.ToInt64(id.SelectedItem);
        break;
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, what I am trying to do, is eliminate my code behind. but I dont know how I can get my richeditbox. For example I coud Have a button with a commandParameter in my xaml and pass the tags as a parametar, but how can I acess my richeditbox. Also how can I change the size of my font. I guess I am trying to do something like this https://pastebin.com/3gjqk3Jn but comboxes dont have commandParameter. Do you think is bad to  have a code in code behind

Comment: If you use the command and want to change the property of the control, generally using binding to achieve(e.g. change the property in vm which bound with the control.) because you can't access your control. However, for richEditBox, you can't directly bind the Document.Selection.CharacterFormat property, so in that case, it's better to change the size or fontFamily in code-behind instead of using command. Inaddition, about how to change the size, I have updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: The code is by changing the font size of the selected text. Did you select the text to change? Or you want to directly change the font size of the whole text?

Comment: both, I tried this, but did not work https://pastebin.com/HDJZHb7q

Comment: When I used your code, it crash at this code `var size = (float)id.SelectedItem;`. It can't  cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Single'. Do you get the same exception? If yes, try to use `Convert.ToInt64(id.SelectedItem)` to convert object type to int and set its value to size. If not, can you describe your issue?